# Alias overwrite flagged as bad indentation of a mapping entry

Tags: yaml

I have an anchor as follows:

```
helm-install
docker-flags: &my_docker_flags
- "--network host"
- "--env KUBECONFIG=/tmp/admin.conf"
- "--env HOME=${env.HOME}"
- "--volume ${env.KUBECONFIG}:/tmp/admin.conf:ro"
- "--volume ${env.PWD}:${env.PWD}"
- "--volume ${env.HOME}/.helm:${env.HOME}/.helm"
- "--volume
${var.docker_config_basepath}:${var.docker_config_basepath}"
```

later I want to do:

```
  docker-flags:
    <<: *my_docker_flags
    - "--env K8_NAMESPACE=${env.K8_NAMESPACE}"
```

But, the last line is flagged as bad indentation of a mapping entry YAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YAML merge key `<<`, [defined here](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html), is a feature defined for outdated YAML 1.1. It has never been part of the spec and thus its implementation is optional. Lots of YAML implementations implemented it and it remains a feature even while they get updated for YAML 1.2, which doesn't define this feature.

As a „key“, it is not a special syntax feature. Instead, much like the scalar `true`, it gets interpreted as something special because of its content. Supporting implementations will treat it according to the linked specification when it occurs as key in a mapping.

However, a sequence like the one you are showing is a different data structure: It contains a sequence of items. There is no place to put a merge key here, so you cannot use this feature in a sequence.

Generally, YAML is not a data processing language. `<<` was and is an exception to that, there are no other processing features – neither for merging sequences, nor for different operations you would expect from a data processing language, like e.g. concatenation of strings.

For this reason, lots of tools that heavily use YAML, such as Ansible or Helm, include some kind of template processing for their YAML input files. While far from perfect, templating is currently the most versatile way to do data processing in a YAML file.

If the tool that reads your YAML doesn't provide you with a templating engine, your only option is to pre-process the YAML file manually, for example using a simple templating engine like [mustache](https://mustache.github.io). Whether that is feasible depends of course on the context.

Comment: Thanks, however, my file is not a helm chart but a ruleset

Comment: @boardtc Can you be a bit more specific about which tool is reading your YAML (e.g. add relevant tags to your question)? What you want to do is definitely not possible with YAML alone so you're dependent on whatever template capabilities the tool that processes the YAML provides.

Comment: That's not the news I was hoping for :-( The ruleset YAML file will be parsed via a docker run. So, my understanding is that it's not an issue adding to a YAML merge if there are key-value pairs but it's not possible when the key has multiple values like in my example?

Comment: @boardtc Yes. Actually the YAML merge key `<<` is only defined for outdated YAML 1.1 and most YAML 1.2 implementations just keep supporting it. But generally, YAML is not a data processing language and therefore does not have the capabilities necessary for things like this. This is why you find various templating languages in tools that depend heavily on YAML, like Ansible, Helm and others.

Comment: It's frustrating that YAML has not been updated in over 10 years especially considering how much used it still is. If you turn your last comment and the first paragraph of the answer into an answer I can vote for it, thanks.

Comment: Anyone can make a suggestion how to change the YAML language. But it needs more than "`<<` should also merge sequences". Because that is simply not possible. See issues [62](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/62), [48](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/48) and [35](https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/35) on how complicated it would be.

Comment: @boardtc I reworded my answer. Btw, I did prototype an extension for YAML once that implemented some transformations, [see here](https://ada.yaml.io/trans/). The takeaway from this was that yes, it is possible, but it is so complex that other YAML implementations are unlikely to implement support for it and even if they try, it is hard to get it right. Therefore, I abandoned the goal to properly specify it as official YAML extension.

Comment: Thanks, @tinita. To complete my train of thought on this, one can alias sequences, e.g. docker-flags: *my_docker_flags, so merging them would be a natural progression.... a pity coding architectures have blocked development and obvious extensions of YAML